Reverb works on main domain but fails on subdomains - How to enable subdomain Support?
I'm using Laravel 11 with Reverb for real-time communication, and it works perfectly on the main domain (e.g., domainname.com), but when I try to access the Reverb-enabled features from subdomains (e.g., erp.domainname.com, api.domainname.com or seller.domainname.com), the connection fails. I've configured subdomain routing in Laravel and checked CORS settings, but the issue persists. How can I ensure Reverb works with both the main domain and subdomains?
.env
APP_DOMAIN=reverb-app.test
APP_URL="http://${APP_DOMAIN}"

BROADCAST_CONNECTION=reverb

REVERB_APP_ID=
REVERB_APP_KEY=
REVERB_APP_SECRET=
REVERB_HOST="${APP_DOMAIN}"
REVERB_ERP_HOST="$erp.{APP_DOMAIN}"
REVERB_SELLER_HOST="seller.${APP_DOMAIN}"
REVERB_PORT=6001
REVERB_SCHEME=http

VITE_REVERB_APP_KEY="${REVERB_APP_KEY}"
VITE_REVERB_HOST="${REVERB_HOST}"
VITE_REVERB_ERP_HOST="${REVERB_ERP_HOST}"
VITE_REVERB_SELLER_HOST="${REVERB_SELLER_HOST}"
VITE_REVERB_PORT="${REVERB_PORT}"
VITE_REVERB_SCHEME="${REVERB_SCHEME}"

resources/js/bootstrap.js
import axios from "axios";
window.axios = axios;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";

/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allow your team to quickly build robust real-time web applications.
 */

import "./echo";
import "./erp_echo";
import "./seller_echo";


resources/js/echo.js
import Echo from "laravel-echo";

import Pusher from "pusher-js";
window.Pusher = Pusher;
console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_HOST);
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: "reverb",
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_HOST,
    wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_PORT ?? 80,
    wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_PORT ?? 443,
    forceTLS: (import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_SCHEME ?? "https") === "https",
    enabledTransports: ["ws", "wss"],
});


resources/js/erp_echo.js
import Echo from "laravel-echo";

import Pusher from "pusher-js";
window.Pusher = Pusher;
console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_HOST);
window.ErpEcho = new Echo({
    broadcaster: "reverb",
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_ERP_HOST,
    wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_PORT ?? 80,
    wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_PORT ?? 443,
    forceTLS: (import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_SCHEME ?? "https") === "https",
    enabledTransports: ["ws", "wss"],
});

resources/js/seller_echo.js
import Echo from "laravel-echo";

import Pusher from "pusher-js";
window.Pusher = Pusher;
console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_HOST);
window.SellerEcho = new Echo({
    broadcaster: "reverb",
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_SELLER_HOST,
    wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_PORT ?? 80,
    wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_PORT ?? 443,
    forceTLS: (import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_SCHEME ?? "https") === "https",
    enabledTransports: ["ws", "wss"],
});

How can I make sure the reverb can work with the main domain and subdomains in Laravel 11? Thanks in advance.
I set up WebSockets in Laravel 11 using Reverb for both the main domain and subdomains, but it's not working.
